# Convert the result of select to array

Tags: powershell

I have the following code.

```
$l = @("A", "B", "X", "Y")
echo "A,B,X`n1,2,3,4" > .\myFile # Create test file

$f = cat myFile | ConvertFrom-Csv | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | select Name
compare $l $f

$a = .... # convert $f to array
compare $l $a
```

How to convert the `$f` to array so it can be compared with an array? Bracing `@(...)` doesn't work.

I got the following result when compare `$l` and `$f`.

```
PS C:\Users\nick> compare $l $f

InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
@{Name=A}                                                   =>
@{Name=B}                                                   =>
@{Name=X}                                                   =>
A                                                           <=
B                                                           <=
X                                                           <=
Y                                                           <=
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `select Name` with `select -Expand Name` or `ForEach-Object { $_.Name }`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, if you are looking to get an array from a single property would be to use the "ExpandProperty" switch from `Select` like this:

```
$f = cat myFile | ConvertFrom-Csv | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast both objects to ArrayLists then compare them.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$array1 = $l
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$array2 = $f
```

Comment: I got the same result when comparing $array1 and $array2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
$f | % { $null = $a.Add($_.Name); }
compare $l $a;
```